# Math equation behind ColorSpace.CS_GRAY method in java

Tags: java, image-processing, color-space, image-conversion

which mathematical equation used in **ColorSpace.CS_GRAY** method in java to convert GrayScale image ?

Comment: The question is missing much context. In its current state it is very difficult to answer. You also seem to be asking different  questions in one. Which method to convert to grayscale should be used and how to implement that in java. Only the latter question would be approriate for this site.

Comment: hi SpaceTrucker I want to know which maths formula applied behind this "cs_gray" ? I don't want to know how to implement in java. thanks

Comment: This is a very good question, I hope they're using one of the established methods to convert from RGB to Y, Y being the luma component of YUV. But it could also just be the intensity (R + G + B)/3.

Comment: Agree with @SpaceTrucker. `CS_GRAY` is a color space. Are you asking about color space *conversion*? If so, that only makes sense if you also specify which color space you want to convert to or from. Please add context to clarify what you are asking. As it stands, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Usually the formula is this: 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B